# MySQL jdbc + SSL

Tags: java, mysql, sockets, ssl, jdbc

I set system properties for a SSL-enabled MySQL client, which worked fine:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","truststore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","12345");
String url = "jdbc:mysql://abc.com:3306/test?" +
             "user=abc&password=123" +
             "&useUnicode=true" +
             "&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=true"
```

A couple days ago I found the client couldn't connect to another web site in which a commercially signed SSL certificate is installed. Obviously the overriding keystores didn't work with regular https connections.
Then I decided to build my version of SocketFactory based on StandardSocketFactory.java in MySQL Connector/J source.

I added a method to create Socket objects in public Socket connect(String hostname, int portNumber, Properties props) method.

```
private Socket createSSLSocket(InetAddress address, int port) {
    Socket socket;

    try {
        InputStream trustStream = new FileInputStream(new File("truststore"));
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

                    // load the stream to your store
        trustStore.load(trustStream, trustPassword);

        // initialize a trust manager factory with the trusted store
        TrustManagerFactory trustFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("PKIX", "SunJSSE");                  trustFactory.init(trustStore);

        // get the trust managers from the factory
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustFactory.getTrustManagers();

        // initialize an ssl context to use these managers and set as default
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sslContext.init(null, trustManagers, null);
        if(address == null) {
            socket = sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
        } else {
            socket = sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(address, port);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        return null;
    }
    return socket;
}
```

The url passed to jdbc driver is changed to:

```
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://abc.com:3306/test?" +
             "user=abc&password=123" +
             "&useUnicode=true" +
             "&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=true" +
             "&socketFactory=" + MySocketFactory.class.getName();
```

The client did execute my version createSSLSocket() and return a Socket object. However, I got the following Exceptions after continuing the execution:

```
    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: 
    Communications link failure

    The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: 
    Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

I'm sure the MySQL was up and running, the address and port passed to createSSLSocket() were correct. Could anyone help? The client has to communicate to 2 sites at the same time: an HTTPS web server and a self-signed MySQL server.