# Set custom SSL truststore only for mysql jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, ssl, jdbc

I would like to be able to connect to a MySQL server with JDBC through an SSL connection.
The [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html) states that we should set system properties:

`java
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","path_to_truststore_file");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","password");`

Indeed, it works... for MySQL. But once I've set those system properties, I cannot make regular HTTPS calls to registered websites. The system trustore has been overriden, and I get an `SSLHandshakeException`.

I'd like to be able to set the trustore ONLY for the JDBC MySQL connection. Any regular HTTPS call should use the system trust store.
How can it be done ?

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666906/mysql-jdbc-ssl) that may lead to an answer but it looks like it's not working.

Answer (score 8):

Turns out the MySQL JDBC driver allows to [override those properties as part of the connection URL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html).

So I need to add `&trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file://path_to_truststore_file&trustCertificateKeyStorePassword=password` to the connection URL.